# Since Spark 2.3, the queries from raw JSON/CSV files are disallowed

Tags: python, json, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Hi i am learning `pyspark` now and it currently working for the csv data but if i convert it into `json` data i am getting an error

***Since Spark 2.3**, the queries from raw `JSON/CSV` files are disallowed when the
referenced columns only include the internal corrupt record column
(named _corrupt_record by default). For example:

```
spark.read.schema(schema).json(file).filter($"_corrupt_record".isNotNull).count()
```

and `spark.read.schema(schema).json(file).select("_corrupt_record").show()`.
Instead, you can cache or save the parsed results and then send the same query.
For example, `val df = spark.read.schema(schema).json(file).cache()` and then

```
df.filter($"_corrupt_record".isNotNull).count().*
```

the sample json data is

```
[
  {
    "student_id": 1,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 18,
    "grade": "A"
  },
  {
    "student_id": 2,
    "name": "Jane Smith",
    "age": 17,
    "grade": "B"
  },
  {
    "student_id": 3,
    "name": "Bob Johnson",
    "age": 19,
    "grade": "C"
  },
  {
    "student_id": 4,
    "name": "Alice Williams",
    "age": 18,
    "grade": "A"
  },
  {
    "student_id": 5,
    "name": "Charlie Brown",
    "age": 17,
    "grade": "B"
  },
  {
    "student_id": 6,
    "name": "Emma Davis",
    "age": 19,
    "grade": "C"
  },
  {
    "student_id": 7,
    "name": "James Miller",
    "age": 18,
    "grade": "A"
  },
  {
    "student_id": 8,
    "name": "Sophie Taylor",
    "age": 17,
    "grade": "B"
  },
  {
    "student_id": 9,
    "name": "David White",
    "age": 19,
    "grade": "C"
  }
]
```

and the python code that i have used is

```
mydata = spark.read.json("/original.csv")
mydata.show()
```

Comment: The text you found is not hinting on what you are doing. When processing JSON or CSV data, Spark creates an internal column in your dataframe that contains information about corrupt records (rows) in your original data. That column is called `_corrupt_record`. The text tells you that you can not directly query on that column name, but you have to persist the dataframe first by a `cache` or a `save`. Remember: Spark is lazy evaluating your data and it will only process the data when persisted.

Answer (score 1):

Spark while processing json data considers each new line as a complete json hence it is failing.

Try using this:

```
mydata = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json("/original.csv")
mydata.show()
```

or

```
spark.read.json("/original.csv", multiLine=true)
```

[https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-json.html#:~:text=read-,multiLine,-false](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-json.html#:%7E:text=read-,multiLine,-false)

Comment: also if you find the answer useful you can ✔️ so that other fellow stack members know if he find same doubt as yours